# How to populate a treeview from SQL Server dynamically to get all table and column names

Tags: sql-server, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm using this connection string to connect to SQL Server

I'm trying to populate nodes... but I am not able to do so.

I am able to get only table names but not child nodes (i.e column names)

```
connetionString = "Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + comboBox1.Text + ";User ID=" + textBox2.Text + ";Password=" + textBox3.Text;

sql = "SELECT * FROM [sys].[tables]";

connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

TreeView mytree = new TreeView();

try
{
    connection.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(ds, "SQL Temp Table");
    adapter.Dispose();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();

    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Sort();

    for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());

        for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to select from  `sys.columns` to get the column names; the `object_id` in `sys.columns` corresponds to the `object_id` in `sys.tables`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. let me try @marc_s...

Answer (score 0):

I think this query may help you

select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table1'[image]

Comment: Hi pavan,Thanks for reply. I am already using This Query where i am getting table fields and columns. but i need to populate same  to treeview. How to achieve this ?                                                                                              SELECT T.[name] AS [table_name], AC.[name] AS [column_name]   
FROM sys.[tables] AS T   
  INNER JOIN sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]